# How to forward to another route at Module.php without redirect?

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I wish to show login form at page being accessed without url redirection. Is it possible to forward route at Module.php, i.e. if client accesses /stations/ forward it to "user/login" route? Without external redirect, I just want to see login form at private pages.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){
    # .... other
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'checkAuth'), -100);
}
public function checkAuth(MvcEvent $e){
    # ... get auth service 
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
        # smth like this
        $router   = $e->getRouter()->setRoutes(array('zfcuser/login'));
        return $router;
    }
    return;
}
```

This code throws `Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find prototype with name zfcuser/login'`.

So the question is the following: how can I substitute route at Module.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved thanks to @samsonasik comment to another question.

```
public function checkAuth(MvcEvent $e){
    # ... get auth service 
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $e->getRouteMatch()
                     ->setParam('controller', 'zfcuser')
                     ->setParam('action', 'login');
    }
    return;
}
```

So I have changed route without external redirection.